# What is the most elegant/efficient way to determine if many variables are unique?

Tags: c#

If I have five variables

```
int a,b,c,d,e;
```

What is the most efficient way to make sure they are all unique?

```
if(a!=b && a!=c && a!=d && a!=e && b!=c && b!=d && b!=e && c!=d && c!=e && d!=e)
{ 
   //Is this the most efficient way??
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That pretty much *is* the most efficient way. It's not necessarily the best looking code I've seen but it'll work just fine. Any other solution involving data structures or functions is unlikely to be faster.

I'd recode it for beauty though:

```
if (a != b && a != c && a != d && a != e
           && b != c && b != d && b != e
                     && c != d && c != e
                               && d != e
) { 
    // Blah blah blah
}
```

Not necessarily *exactly* like that, just something a bit easier on the eyes when reading.

Comment: For five variables, it might be.  But hash tables will be faster for larger sets.

Comment: Concur, @Ben, but the question specifically stated "if I have five variables".

Answer (score 11):

**Elegant**

```
int[] arr = { a, b, c, d, e };

bool b = arr.Distinct().Count() == arr.Length;
```

**Efficient**

```
Your code is the most efficient
```

I guess that is the most simple explanation of your question.

Comment: This is easy to code and it's pretty clear what it does, but it's nothing like the most efficient test.

Comment: @TedHopp: That `most efficient test` of OP will fail if number of variables increases. `Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for a lifetime`

Comment: OP specifically asked for the most efficient test involving five variables, not a robust approach for N variables.

Comment: I prefer "Give a man a fire, he'll be warm for the night. _Set_ him on fire and he'll be warm for the rest of his life." :-) From memory, I think that's from Discworld or something from Pratchett. In any case, this answer matches the elegance part of the question so it's still useful.

Comment: If you have 20 or 30 or 50 _variables_ in your method, you might reconsider that design anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like:

```
int[] x = new int[] {a,b,c,d,e};
if (x == x.Distinct().ToArray())
{
}
```

Comment: Use `.ToArray()` after `.Distinct()` as will return `IEnumerable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

If we're playing code golf we can knock this all down to one line and shave 6 characters:

```
bool d = (new int[]{ a, b, c, d, e })
              .GroupBy(i => i)
              .Where(i => i.Count() > 1)
              .Any();
```

Comment: Elegant OK. Efficient Not OK.